# Force One Line Break in Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, line-breaks

I have a 'li' item that contains a label which pops up a Bootstrap tooltip.

```
<label class="radio dropClick centTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Here are some words that will show up in the tooltip">
    <input type="radio" class="centTooltip" name="cents" id="optionsRadios2" value="AA">
    Hover for ToolTip! 
</label>
```

How do I force one line break between 'that' and 'will'?  I don't want to use the tooltip's() `{html : true}` option for risk of XSS attacks.

Comment: Different question.  I don't want to apply line-wrapping to the entire div, I just want insert a singular line break.

Comment: The first answer to that question makes the tooltip respect new lines. If you insert a singular line break, that's what you will get.

Answer (score 5):

Decent answer I found, using the semi-duplicate above, is to set the CSS as:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```